# Insert object into table, and have table populated by it's properties

Tags: c#, mysql

I currently have two classes: `Bha` and `BhaItem`. `BhaItem` has about 7 properties, and `Bha` contains a `List<BhaItem>`.

BhaItem.cs

```
class BhaItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Od { get; set; }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int BhaID { get; set; }
    public int BHANumber { get; set; }

    public BhaItem()
    {

    }

    public BhaItem(int number, string newDesc, decimal newOd, decimal newLength, DateTime date,int bhaNumber, int id = 0)
    {
        Description = newDesc;
        Od = newOd;
        Length = newLength;
        Date = date;
        Number = number;
        BhaID = id;
        BHANumber = bhaNumber;
    }
}
```

Bha.cs

```
class Bha
    {
        public List<BhaItem> BHAItems;
        public int BHANumber { get; set; }

        public Bha()
        {

        }

        public Bha(int number)
        {
            BHANumber = number;
        }

        public Bha(List<BhaItem> bhaItemList)
        {
            BHAItems = bhaItemList;
        }
    }
```

Now, I've got corresponding tables in a local database, `Bha` and `BhaItem` with a column for each property. However, I'm needing a way to query the `Bha` table, and retrieve the appropriate items from the `BhaItem` table. I initially thought doing a query to get the `BHANumber`'s, and then using that to query the `BhaItem` table for the items. But this seems extremely inefficient. Plus, I'd like to be able to insert a Bha into it's table, and - if possible - have the `BhaItem`s inserted into the `BhaItem` table. I'm still fairly green when it comes to database interactions. I know enough to `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE`. But many of the other complex cool things that can be done, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you trying to get one Bha and all of its items? Or you want all Bhas, each of which has all of its items already loaded from the DB?

Comment: @Mikeb: I'd like to get all the Bha's, each with all of it's items.

Comment: Create a view and use that perhaps? In terms of querying the data in the DB you would use an INNER JOIN (If you wanted all BHA that had BHAItems) or a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you wanted all BHA whether they had items or not

Comment: @DanielDawes: A view?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you start using Entity Framework, you'll have to join your tables with SQL commands and traverse them the hard way to populate your List for each BHA object.

Example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6918201/1293496